# Reshaping data and seperation by multiple delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry but I need some help with pandas data wrangling. 
I have a large dataset in excel. Each cell contains data from several days. I have loaded the data with pandas, but I haven't found a desirable way of separating it into individual cells. 
The format is "Date" space dash space "value" Pipe and repeated as such 20100205 - 0.10 |

I want to separate the cell such that I have a cell with the date and corresponding value below.

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------
|   ID      | WBC
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------
|     1     | 20100205 - 0.10 |20100205 - 0.16 |20100205 - 0.21 etc..
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------

Ideal:
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   ID     |   20100205  |   20100205  |  20100205  |   
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|    1     |     0.10    |    0.16     |    0.21    | 
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = {'ID': ['1'],
        'WBC': ["20100205 - 0.10 |20100205 - 0.16 |20100205 - 0.21 |20100305 - 71.69 |20100306 - 0.27 |20100306 - 0.42 |20100306 - 1.42"]
        }
df = DataFrame (data,columns= ['ID', 'WBC'])
```

Comment: For each WBC, parse this delimited data, return keys and values. Create a data frame with that information, passing the ID as index.

Comment: Change only splitters in dupe.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks it is a useful answer - but I would not call it a duplicate. You still need to change several things to get the wanted result. Besides the headline "How to split a column into three columns in pandas" well not exactly what I would have searched for.. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is to parse the information in your `WBC` column and then create the new columns as required:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'ID': ['1'],
        'WBC': ["20100205 - 0.10 |20100205 - 0.16 |20100205 - 0.21 |20100305 - 71.69 |20100306 - 0.27 |20100306 - 0.42 |20100306 - 1.42"]
        }
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['ID', 'WBC'])

df["WBC"] = df["WBC"].str.split("|")
dates = [x.split(" - ")[0] for x in df.loc[0, "WBC"]]
vals = [x.split(" - ")[1] for x in df.loc[0, "WBC"]]

for i in range(len(dates)):
    df[int(dates[i])] = float(vals[i])

df.drop("WBC", axis=1, inplace=True)
# df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)    # If you want this as your index
```

This then leaves you with:

```
df

    ID      20100205     20100305   20100306    20100205    20100305    20100306
0   1           0.21        71.69       1.42        0.21       71.69        1.42
```

(Ideally, your data frame should however have unique column names).

Comment: Thank you for this Tom.. I have a lot of issues with this data frame, I would like to bounce some ideas of you if possible?

Comment: @Strangelove Sure, no problem, fire away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763302/tom Well, it is another issue that I am trying to solve. different dataset and I don't know where to start - please help  https://pastebin.com/SFGq4UFE

Comment: @Strangelove The best thing to do would be to post it as another question here on SO and show what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: if you have any ideas - let me know ..
I might post later today - when I have smacked my laptop around a bit